# Is it possible to use CPP code with compile setting USE_CUDNN := 1?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

In caffe, I must choose the setting `USE_CUDNN := 1` when compile. I will write a new layer with .hpp and .cpp code (without .cu). Can I still use my layer if I did not write cuda code (.cu)? For example, I will setup the layer with `engine=CAFFE`

Answer (score 2):

You may have layers that have only CPU implementation. See [development](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Development) page for instruction on what changes are required to make your layer a "CPU only".

However, note that when forwarding/backprop-ing through your net, data will be copied form GPU to CPU memory every time data is passed through your layer. This back and forth memory sync can take significant amount of time and significantly stall your computations. In most cases it is worth while making an effort and implementing a GPU version for the layer as well.

Comment: Thanks. So, Do I need any setting for using CPU version. I tried   `batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: false
    engine:CAFFE
  }` but it did not work

Comment: @user8264 `batch_norm_param` is only used by the BatchNorm layer. You do not need to specify the engine.